# How do I find the difference in time between yesterday and today in pandas?

Tags: python

I want to find out how much time as passed from last night to today morning. What is the quickest way to do this? The format of the pandas dataframe is shown here. [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W9Si.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for timedelta. Read this:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_timedelta.htm

Comment: When I tried this code, I got negative numbers. For example, it was not calculating from 10pm to 6am, it was calculating from 6am to 10pm

df.sleep_time = pd.to_datetime(df.sleep_time)
df.wake_time = pd.to_datetime(df.wake_time)
sleeping_hours = (df.wake_time - df.sleep_time)
df['sleep_hours'] = (sleeping_hours / pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
df['sleep_hours'].head()

@Babbel

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype is not already datetime, you can use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
frm = '%H:%M'  #format
delta = datetime.strptime(df['wake_time'][row_number], frm) - datetime.strptime(df['sleep_time'][row_number], frm)
```

*assuming your pandas dataframe is named df and the row index is row_number